# shorthand way to reference `this` propeties?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  Bar() {
    console.log(this.x, this.y)
}
```

I recall seeing a method of referring to `this.` variables without having to specify `this.` Something like

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(x,y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  Bar() {
    x,y = [this] // something like this
    console.log(x, y) // equivalent to this.x, this.y
}
```

I desire this because I have dozens of statements that call methods on `this.ctx` - like `this.ctx.rect()` - and I don't want to have to have `this.` prepended to all of them for the sake of readability.

Is there a syntax for this?

Comment: But you want to do `x, y = [this]` everywhere instead?

Comment: `Object.assign(this, { x, y });`? And what is `Bar` supposed to be? Currently, it’s a syntax error.

Comment: `const { x, y } = this`? Which doesn't save a whole lot, AFAIC.

Comment: I hope you don't remember `with(this)`?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Correct, many of my class methods will have upwards of 5 lines of code referencing `this.ctx`, so sacrificing one line at the start to make the other ones shorter seems like a good trade off.

Comment: It depends.  If `this.x` is a number/string/boolean, and you do `const {x} = this`, and then you modify `x`, it will not be reflected in `this.x`

Comment: Noting that depending on the *type* of `x` and `y` this may not be what you *actually* want, which is why destructuring is not a *generic* replacement. (I don't recall if adding setters solves that problem or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deconstruct `this` like any JavaScript object,

```
Bar() {
    const {x, y} = this;
}
```

I do not recommend doing this however, it seems like it would not scale well as a technique.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain what "not scaling well" in this context means :)

Comment: `{ a, b, ..., z, ... }` can get really out of hand. Plus, what if some are needed to be `const` and others `var`?

Comment: The context that I saw this syntax in was a "coding tips" video, implying that this was something you'd want to do in cases where you call this variables many times. Was that guy just wrong, and there aren't any cases where this would be good practice?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Use multiple destructures (but who needs `var`?)

Comment: @MichaelMoreno It's not *wrong*, it's just less useful than it might seem. In longer methods it can be a little misleading because it's not be immediately clear what's being referenced. In reasonably-sized methods it doesn't save much visual noise (IMO, YMMV). It's very context-dependent and primarily opinion-oriented.

Comment: @DaveNewton, it's probably not typical but it could be needed depending on how you go about things and the point is - what are you saving if that is the case? Two deconstructions? The code in this answer is already longer than just typing `this` in OP's example.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils `var` would never be needed in the context of a class, but that aside: the only time deconstructing is longer is when it's a single deconstruction--this code isn't longer, the OP's example is syntactically invalid. *That* aside, the number of characters in a code fragment is rarely the most useful metric: it's not about code golf, it's about clarity.

Comment: @DaveNewton, this code is longer; look at what OP had not what they were trying to do. For this specific example, there are 21 chars needed to deconstruct to turn the 28 char call to the console with one that's 18 chars.

Comment: @DaveNewton, agreed, chars aren't the *most useful* metric, and clarity was what I was referring to; it's not clear that there's any additional clarity achieved by the deconstruction especially when you consider "it's not be immediately clear what's being referenced", as you said. I rarely see code that is long for the sake of some subjective improvement while at the same time being easier to reason about but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'm not even sure what side you've taken :shrug: There is most certainly code that's deliberately longer precisely so it's easier to reason about, particularly mathematical/formulaic code. A trivial example (e.g., single-letter vars) is not the best platform for showing why (except for math-y things, perhaps).

Comment: I'm not taking a side for all cases, @Dave. I'm saying doing `const {x, y} = this;` to avoid `console.log(this.x, this.y);` is on the same plane as the now popular: "How can I remove all the `if` statements in my code?" and then end up with layers of indirection. Good job! :/ Sure, using (longer) descriptive var names improves the ability to reason about the code; being nitpicky over `this` when `this` tells the reader precisely what is being referenced is trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Just MHO, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Objects (including arrays and functions) are handled by reference, meaning that if you write

`let a = this.ctx;`

then `a` points to the same object as `ctx` and you can do `a.rect()`.

Comment: But doing that for multiple vars would not achieve what they're after.

Comment: Why not? From OP:  *I have dozens of statements that call methods on `this.ctx`* - they seem to just need a shorter reference to the object.

Comment: Take another look. They're trying to remove the repetitive use of `this` but if they have to do `a = this...`, `b = this...`, and so on, they still used multiple `this`s. They're looking for a compact way.

Comment: Alright I am understanding the situation different (though it's a bit hard to demonstrate in comment because there are no linebreaks). @Michael Moreno do you want to clarify?

Comment: @Noam That is at a base level what I want, except that I want to be able to do it for multiple properties in one go. The destructuring method that others posted seems to be the answer to that. `const {x, y} = this;`.

Comment: Ah I see. It should be noted though that `{x, y} = this` extracts `this.x` and `this.y`. If you want to extract `this.ctx` it has to be specified (`{ctx}` or `{x: ctx}` which is shorther but less clear). You can also referece a method if you are using the same method of the same object many times. It really depends on the actual details.